# tf.range() inconsistent result

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was trying to generate an interval from 0 to 1 with N numbers.

```
import tensorflow as tf

N = 200
print(tf.__version__)
for n in range(1,N):
    step = 1.0 / float(n)
    numbs = tf.range(0,step*n,step)
    # print(numbs.numpy())
    x = len(numbs) - n
    if(x!=0):
        print(len(numbs),n,step*n)
```

But in the following cases I am getting different result for `len(numbers)` and `n`

```
62 61 1.0
110 109 1.0
116 115 1.0
122 121 1.0
123 122 1.0
124 123 1.0
```

I am not sure what is going wrong here. Any idea ?

Comment: My guess is that, since floating point numbers are represented as finite precision numbers so when doing ranges involving floating point numbers, this kind of behavior can be expected.

Comment: I was trying ` tf.range(0,1,step)` as well, but result is the same. Is there any remedies ?

Comment: Problem is with `step` not the `step*n`. Because `step*n` is always 1.0. I'm not really aware of any remedy.